# How do add method in jquery.validate.js of bassisstance?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I want to validate my form as not to submit it if it equals a string.I have seen the documentation and tried adding it in my validation code.But doesn't work.I need to know where do i need to put the code(in my file or the file that i downloaded) and if possible the code itself to fulfil my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the method like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("name-of-validation-type", function(value, element) {
    var test = null; //Perform your test here        
    return this.optional(element) || test;
}, 'This is your invalid message.');
```

And then add the class `name-of-validation-type` to the input you want to validate.

You can also pass in additional an array of parameters to the method like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("name-of-validation-type", function(value, element, params) { .....
```

The parameters are passed in like this:

```
$('form').validate({      
    rules : {
        input_name : {
            name-of-validation-type: function(){ return param; }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you don't attach the validator to the form until your document is ready. So wrap your code in `jQuery(function($) { //code to attach validator });`

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to add custom method for the plugin. Like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) { 
  return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value); 
}, "Please specify the correct domain for your documents");
```

[addMethod( name, method, [message] )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage)

**Edited**
[Demo Example Link](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/custom-methods-demo.html)

Comment: i know,but where do i write this code? or do i ass this as a plugin.I have added http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js as plugin but it does not work